# Using AppDomain.UnhandledException in a multithreaded environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I wanted to check if its possible to catch all unhanded exceptions in the same place.

I saw there is the `AppDomain.UnhandledException`.

I have used it like this:

```
public void MainMethod()
{
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);

    new Thread()...
}

static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    LogFile.Log("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
}
```

This works when the unhandled exception occurs in the main thread, but in the inner thread it doesn't catch it.

Is it possible to catch the exceptions from all threads in the same place or do I must wrap it on every thread?

Answer (score 0):

We use this method, try it:

```
    private static void SetupExceptionHandling()
    {
        // Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
        Application.ThreadException += ApplicationThreadException;

        // Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through our handler.
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

        // Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event.
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomainUnhandledException;

        //  This AppDomain-wide event provides a mechanism to prevent exception escalation policy (which, by default, terminates the process) from triggering.
        //  Each handler is passed a UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs instance, which may be used to examine the exception and to mark it as observed.
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerUnobservedTaskException;

        // Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += DispatcherUnhandledException;
    }
```

Comment: I have no ui, so the only relevant is AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException? I already use it but as i wrote it won't catch other threads